# Evaluating product of Upper Incomplete Gamma functions

Tags: summation, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

I have checked several posts but couldn't find the equivalent of $\Gamma(m,a) \cdot \Gamma(m,b)$, where '$\cdot$' means multiplication. I suspect that it can be solved by applying the equivalent of Gamma function $(n-1)!e^{-x}\sum \limits_{k=0}^{m}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$ but then there will be two summations with same limits which I have no clue how to solve
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you understand by $\;\Gamma(m,a)\;$ ? That's not the usual Gamma Function...\

Comment: Its the upper incomplete Gamma function

Comment: I think it'd be a rather good idea to explicitly say that, and not only "Gamma Functions", which can mislead.

Comment: Upper or lower incomplete?  "*" means multiplication (or something else)?  The formula you state only applies when the first argument is a positive integer; is $m$ a positive integer?

Comment: yes m is positive, I have changed the title. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

We have that 
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Gamma (m,a)\Gamma (m,b) = \Gamma (m)^{\,2} Q(m,a)Q(m,b) =   \cr 
  &  = \Gamma (m)^{\,2} e^{\, - \left( {a + b} \right)} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{m - 1} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}
 \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m - 1} {{{b^{\,j} } \over {j!}}}  \cr} 
$$

The sum is over a square in $k,j$ and , also with the help of the following scheme,

[image: Gamma_Inc^2_1]

we can re-write it as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{m - 1} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m - 1} {{{b^{\,j} } \over {j!}}}
  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{m - 1} {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m - 1} {{{a^{\,k} b^{\,j} } \over {k!j!}}} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{s = 0}^{2m - 1} {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{a^{\,k} b^{\,s - k} } \over {k!\left( {s - k} \right)!}}} }
  - \sum\limits_{s = 0}^{m - 1} {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{a^{\,m + k} b^{\,s - k} } \over {\left( {m + k} \right)!\left( {s - k} \right)!}}} }
  - \sum\limits_{s = 0}^{m - 1} {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{a^{\,s - k} b^{\,m + k} } \over {\left( {m + k} \right)!\left( {s - k} \right)!}}} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{s = 0}^{2m - 1} {{{\left( {a + b} \right)^{\,s} } \over {s!}}}
  - a^{\,m} \sum\limits_{s = 0}^{m - 1} {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{a^{\,k} b^{\,s - k} } \over {\left( {m + k} \right)!\left( {s - k} \right)!}}} }
  - b^{\,m} \sum\limits_{s = 0}^{m - 1} {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^s {{{a^{\,s - k} b^{\,k} } \over {\left( {m + k} \right)!\left( {s - k} \right)!}}} }  \cr} 
$$
note the summation extends to $m-1$, not to $m$.

The formula above can be managed in various other ways, but I cannot see 
a way of getting rid of the $m+k$ at denominator.